# Bash conversion file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a .csv file and i wanto to convert it in a .txt file through a bash script
The file appears like [.csv file](https://mega.nz/#!QapESA5S!Xew3WQlVphivIccr9ay3vegkrRqvzsNaM2vgXquWgDw+)

I want to obtain a txt file with this format

```
velocity
List<vector>
300 // number of point
(
(U0 U1 U2)
(U0 U1 U2)
...
...
...
)
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Put a snippet of your CSV directly in the question; there's no need to link to 100KB of arbitrary data.

Comment: After you do that, make some effort yourself to write the converter; this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little ugly, but it does the trick I think:

```
 wc -l < Inlet.csv  | cat - Inlet.csv | awk  -F, 'BEGIN{printf "velocity\nList<vector>\n"} NR==1{printf "%s\n(\n",$1} NR>2{print "("$1 $2 $3")"}END{print ")"}'
```

This does the following:

1. Gets the record count from `wc` and pipes it to
2. cat which concats the number with the file. Number first and pipes it to
3. Awk which splits by comma `-F,`
4. Prints out the junk at the top of your file `'BEGIN{printf "velocity\nList<vector>\n"}`
5. If it's on the first record (the count) `NR==1` it prints it followed by a line feed followed by a parantheses followed by another line feed `{printf "%s\n(\n",$1}`
6. If we are past the header (Record is greater than 2) `NR>2` then we print out the first three fields surrounded by parantheses `{print "("$1 $2 $3")"}`
7. Finally at the end of the processing we print out a final parantheses to close that one we printed out when we were at record 1 in step 5 `END{print ")"}`

Comment: @agc  Thank you. That was really bugging me to beat that thing down with awk. Updated the answer.

Comment: Many thanks JNevill for your accurate answer. Just a last question: is it possible to change the sign (plus or minus) of a column starting from the text file.